# What notification is provided for a lost connection in a C++ gRPC async server

Tags: c++, windows, asynchronous, grpc, keep-alive

I have an async gRPC server for Windows written in C++. I’d like to detect the loss of connection to a client – whether a network connection is lost, or the client crashes, etc. I see references to the keepalive channel arguments, and I’ve tried various combinations of those settings, such as:

```
builder.AddChannelArgument(GRPC_ARG_KEEPALIVE_TIME_MS, 10000);
builder.AddChannelArgument(GRPC_ARG_KEEPALIVE_TIMEOUT_MS, 10000);
builder.AddChannelArgument(GRPC_ARG_KEEPALIVE_PERMIT_WITHOUT_CALLS, 1);
builder.AddChannelArgument(GRPC_ARG_HTTP2_MIN_RECV_PING_INTERVAL_WITHOUT_DATA_MS, 9000);
builder.AddChannelArgument(GRPC_ARG_HTTP2_BDP_PROBE, 1);
```

I've done some testing with a streaming RPC method. If I kill the client process and then try to send data to the client, the lost connection is detected. I don't actually even have to send data. I can set an Alarm object to trigger immediately and that causes the call handler to be cancelled. However, if I don't try to send data (or set an alarm) after killing the client process then there's no notification or callback that I've been able to find/enable. I must not have a complete understanding. So:

1. How does the detection of a lost connection manifest itself for the server? Is there a callback method, or notification of some type? My server doesn’t receive any errors; the completion queue’s ‘Next()’ method never returns, etc.
2. Does this detection work for both unary (call/response) and streaming methods?
3. Does the server detection of a lost connection work whether or not the client has implemented lost connection / keepalive logic?
4. Is there some method besides the keepalive channel arguments that is preferred?

Thanks - any help is appreciated.

Comment: I'm sure there's documentation available that would answer this. Have you read it?

Comment: I've definitely looked for it. Haven't found anything that ties these things together. If you're aware of it, a link would be great!.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `ServerContext::AsyncNotifyWhenDone()` to get a notification when the request has been cancelled.

https://grpc.github.io/grpc/cpp/classgrpc__impl_1_1_server_context_base.html#a0f1289f31257e6dbef57bc901bd7b5f2

Comment: I'm using that now on streaming methods but not for non-streaming methods. Is a non-streaming request cancelable? I'll try it out.

Comment: Yes, cancellation works for both streaming and unary methods.

Comment: Interesting. I'll have to keep looking for a sample. When I tried it with a unary method it threw an exception (or just crashed...can't remember now). Even with streaming a method I don't get a notification right away. I have to do something that interacts with the queue - like set an Alarm as I mentioned in my original post. That's even true for a graceful close when the client cancels the streaming method.